# Exposing method that returns custom object in ADF App Module

Tags: java, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a custom class in my model, and a method in backing bean that calls a method from application module. App module method sends my custom class object as a reply to the backing bean method. I seem to have a problem with exposing my App module method due to my custom class return type.

Do you have any suggestions on this?

Comment: I have done this to pass back both a return code and a message together; so I know it can be done.  What "problem" are you having, exactly?

Comment: It doesn't show up in my appmodule, but all the other methods that have different return type (void, String, int) do.

Comment: Double click on the ApplicationModule's XML (e.g., MyApplAM.xml).  Go to the "Java" tab of the "Overview" tab.  There is a "Client Interface" section with a little pencil next to it.  Click on that.  Do you not see your method listed as "available" on the left-hand side of the shuttle dialog?

Comment: No, that is the problem. I have also tried to manually add it in xml but the jdev keeps deleting it.

Comment: Your custom class must implement `java.io.Serializable` in order to be exposed to the client.  Did you do that?  All the parameter types must be Serializable too, for that matter.

Comment: No,but I'll definitely try that, thanks !